# Toto Unifit Adapter: Renew, Replace, or Reuse?

Tags: toilet, flange

I'm replacing a toilet flange and 4" pipe leading to it.  There is a Toto Unifit adapter on it, that's about 6 years old.   Is there a way to replace the rubber gasket that meets the toilet?   Or should I buy a new adapter at this point?  I assume they don't last forever, and 6 years seems like a good time to replace the whole thing assuming the gasket has some finite life span.  Does it?

I'm hoping answers to this question will come from people with more experience than me with this product, who have seen them reach end of life. (Mine hasn't).

[image]

Comment: Instead of a whole new adapter (I'm not sure what this adapts to where, but that doesn't matter), why not just buy a new gasket?

Comment: @FreeMan Toto toilets are designed to use one of these PVC adapters to adapt the toilet to different rough-ins.  The toilet itself has essentially a 5-inch rough in, via the rubber gasket which rests very close to the wall.  The adapters come in 10, 12, and 14 inch versions so any toilet can be used with any existing rough-in.    A side benefit is that the adapter is installed on the wax ring and you don't have to position the heavy toilet "right the first time" as with wax.   I don't think the gasket is replaceable, but that's part of the question.

Comment: Interesting. We installed a Toto a couple of years ago, and if there was an adapter like this we sure didn't see it! Dunno if the gasket is replaceable or not. Did you ask Toto?

Comment: I sent an email to Toto tech support.  Hopefully will get an answer.  But hoping to hear from Experience here regarding longevity etc.   IDK ... they're not that expensive, maybe I should just replace it without caring if it's necessary or not.  Probably worth the $90 just to not have to clean the vile wax off the underside.